# Django - Dynamic form fields based on foreign key

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic, formset

I'm working on creating a database which has programs and these programs have risks. Some background information: Programs (grandparents) have multiple Characteristics (parents) which have multiple Categories (children). I've already constructed a database containing these, however, I want to add risks to a particular program.

That is, for example i have Risk 1 which i want to add to Program 1. I have to answer the following questions: Which characteristics do Risk 1 have? To answer this, I want to construct a dynamic form field. (Note, the amount of characteristics can by any arbitrary number, as well as the amount of categories each characteristic has).

How do I construct such form? I've tried formsets, however I do not know how to implement those in a practical way (I'm still a bit new with Python).

This is a printscreen of how I want it to be implemented: https://gyazo.com/40c448c0096a9ec5da751ba9883dc912
However, I have no idea what to do. (Note that the possible answers in the drop down menu are the categories that correspond to that particular Characteristic).
This is what I'm getting: https://gyazo.com/25fd18e2f31e6931bfd3639ce4be632c

This is the corresponding code I have thus far:

```
# views.py 
def risk_create(request):
program = get_object_or_404(Program, id=20)
RiskFormSet = formset_factory(RiskForm, ...
    ... extra=len(Program.objects.get(id=program.id).char_set.all()))
context = {
    'title': 'New Risk',
    'form': RiskFormSet
}
return render(request, 'risk_form.html', context)


# forms.py
class RiskForm(forms.Form):
for char in Program.objects.get(id=20).char_set.all():
    char = forms.ModelChoiceField(char.cat_set.all(), label=char)
```

I'VE FOUND MY ANSWER.

```
class RiskForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    programid = kwargs.pop('programid', None)
    super(RiskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for i in range(0,len(Program.objects.get(id=programid).char_set.all())):
        charid = Program.objects.get(id=programid).char_set.all()[i].id
        charlabel = Program.objects.get(id=programid).char_set.all()[i].label
        self.fields['char_field_%i' %i] = forms.ModelChoiceField(Char.objects.get(id=charid).cat_set.all(), label=charlabel)
```

Comment: Edit: Lets say i have a queryset of characters (Char.objects.filter(program__id=char.program_id). I want to make a form based on this queryset. That is, say this queryset has 4 characteristics. My form needs to have 4 fields, which ask for the category of each characteristic

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question, are you asking how to pre-populate the form fields? If so consider using [initial values in your formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset)

Comment: No, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding due to the fact that in the second print screen, the initial values are set as -------. In the first print screen I've already set them to a value by hand. The question is rather, how to dynamically define 'char' (thus the variable gets the char label) in the last line of code. This is not passible, however, I want to know a workaround